# Is there an Ambiance theme available for Windows?

Tags: windows, themes, ambiance

I tend to run Windows apps with VirtualBox in seamless mode (so that virtualized Windows applications windows and Windows taskbar appear alongside host OS windows instead of a separate virtual machine screen). To make the experience even more "seamless" I'd like Windows theming (especially windows' title bars and a taskbar) to look exactly as Ubuntu windows look. So it seems that I need a Windows clone of Ubuntu Ambiance theme. Is there one?

I'm ok to have Windows minimize/maximize buttons on the right, as I've switched Ubuntu to the same classic mode.

I am interested in both Windows XP *and Windows 7* themes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-windows-xp-wine/), you can download it [here](http://freddi67.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Light-for-Windows-XP-177514325). This theme is for Windows XP and while it has a few bugs, outlined in the download link, it should be an improvement on what you have now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this omgubuntu blogpost](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-windows-xp-wine/).

[image]